# creating multiple xml nodes with same namespaces in php

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, xml-namespaces

I have the following code

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');        
    $headerNS = $dom->createElementNS('http://somenamespace', 'ttauth:authHeader');
    $accesuser = $dom->createElementNS('http://somenamespace', 'ttauth:Accessuser','aassdd');
    $accesscode = $dom->createElementNS('http://somenamespace', 'ttauth:Accesscode','aassdd');
    $headerNS->appendChild($accesuser);
    $headerNS->appendChild($accesscode);

    echo "<pre>";
    echo ($dom->saveXML($headerNS));
    echo "</pre>";
```

IT will produce the following xml as output

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ttauth:authHeader xmlns:ttauth="http://somenamespace">
<ttauth:Accessuser>
    ApiUserFor136
</ttauth:Accessuser>
<ttauth:Accesscode>
    test1234
</ttauth:Accesscode>
</ttauth:authHeader>
```

But I want the following output

```
<ttauth:authHeader xmlns:ttauth="http://somenamespace">

  <ttauth:Accessuser xmlns:ttauth="http://somenamespace">
    aassdd
  </ttauth:Accessuser>

  <ttauth:Accesscode xmlns:ttauth="somenamespace">
    aassdd
  </ttauth:Accesscode>

</ttauth:authHeader>
```

See the **xmlns is not included in elements other than root element but I want xmlns to be included in all elements** Is there anything I am doing wrong ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the PHP parser does not add renaming of the same namespace "http://somenamespace" with the same prefix "ttauth" because it is redundant. Both xmls you shown ( the output and expected ) are equivalent. If you want to be sure you have the namespaces attributes as you want, you should add them manually by using addAtribute - http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createattribute.php. See the following code snippet:

```
$domAttribute = $domDocument->createAttribute('xmlns:ttauth');
$domAttribute->value = 'http://somenamespace';
$accessuser->appendChild($domAttribute);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: There is one problem with this too. When I append the same attribute to two child nodes it doesn't work :(

Comment: That is a correct behavior. You should create different attribute for every child node even if it has the same content.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

```
$accesuser = $dom->createElementNS('http://somenamespace', 'ttauth:Accessuser','aassdd');
```

I used

```
$accesuser = $dom->createElement('http://somenamespace', 'ttauth:Accessuser','aassdd');
```

and then

```
$accesuser->setAttribute('xmlns:ttauth', ('http://somenamespace');
```

it works fine for any number of nodes